# Is Cython/Jython an independent language?

Tags: java, python, c, jython, cython

So I spent a lot of time trying to fugure out what `Cython` and `Jython` are and I'm still (more) confused as anyone who just started computer programming. I heard that `Cython` is an extension, but..is *also* and indepent language??

What I *think* I've understood is that:

1. `Cython`/`Jython` is just `Python` and you can use `C` or `C++`/`Java` libraries respectively with just a little bit of `Cython`/`Jython` syntax.
2. It's meant to speed up performance as well as improve code readability when a task would be more efficient to write in `C` or `C++`/`Java` and, this is done by using statically typed variables.

Or is `Cython`/`Jython` just some sort of extension that is used *sometimes* but not independently? What I mean is, you'd still write everything in `Python` and then, for the tasks you'd rather use `C` or `C++`/`Java` for, you'd use `Cython`/`Jython` instead? (I know I still need Python installed and similar things as it's dependent.)

Because if it really is better, other than the barrier that it's still being developed since it's rather new, wouldn't the need for `C` or `C++`/`Java` **completely** go away as these are as easy as `Python` but as powerful as `C` or `C++`/`Java`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[**Jython FAQ:**](https://wiki.python.org/jython/JythonFaq/GeneralInfo)

> Jython is an *implementation* of the Python language for the Java platform. Jython 2.7 *implements the same language* as CPython 2.7, and nearly all of the Core Python standard library modules. (CPython is the C implementation of the Python language.)

Writing Jython is similar to writing standard Python. The main difference is that since it compiles to Java Bytecode you can smoothly interact with Java Libraries. Of course it has a requirement on the JVM but has no Global Interpreter Lock (Famous GIL).

[**Cython**](https://www.cython.org):

> Cython is an optimising static compiler for both the Python programming language and the extended Cython programming language (based on Pyrex)

So, Cython is first of all considered a *compiler*. It compiles your Python code to `C` which you then compile (with a standard `C` compiler) and run.

To further facilitate the integration with `C/C++` it also has extended Syntax for specifying types, defining different kinds of functions and interfacing with `C/C++` code. These, on one hand, allow Cython to generate more efficient code that by-passes the slow interpretation the Python VM usually does and, on the other, make writing extentions for Python a walk in the park since you don't need to familiarize with the `Python C-API`.

---

So, to answer your questions:

> Cython/Jython is just Python and you can use C or C++/Java libraries respectively with just a little bit of Cython/Jython syntax.

Pretty much, yes. Jython **is** Python and uses `Java Libraries` with basic `import` statements. Cython is *very similar* to Python and, as you said, uses a bit of syntax to interface with `C/C++`.

> It's meant to speed up performance as well as improve code readability when a task would be more efficient to write in C or C++/Java; and this is done by using statically typed variables.

For `Cython` this is the **goal**, for `Jython` it isn't. This is why `Cython` provides extended syntax to specify types while `Jython` does not.

Both languages are used *independently* (in the sense that you mean) but, Cython is usually deployed after profiling CPU-bound Python code and determining bottlenecks.

Comment: So from what I understand, once Cython becomes more mature, there will be absolutely no need of Python as it's basically Python but faster and acts just like a programming language by itself?

Comment: @NeelKamath I wouldn't take it to that extreme. `Cython` isn't developed with the goal of replacing `Python`, rather, `Cython` is developed with the goal of complementing `Python` and providing benefits where they are required (i.e scientific computing). The workflow for working with `Cython` and `Python` is generally: Develop in `Python`, **profile** your code and detect bottlenecks, rewrite bottlenecks in `Cython` to speed up execution.

Comment: You use a profiler to profile your code and discover how the frequency and duration of each function call, take a look [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html) for Python profilers. A bottleneck is a section (or function) in your code that performs badly, take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottleneck_(software)) for more.

Answer (score 2):

Ok. Jython is an implementation of Python that converts python source code into java bytecode or object code as most people call it. So you basically write your programs using the python syntax, but the output of the source code when compiled to an object code is the java bytecode

Cython on the other hand is an implementation where by standard modules in the python language have been translated into the C language. So here, when you basically use a module, it is the python standard module, but for efficiency sake, under the hood, its C language or code that is executed

Answer (score 1):

CPython is comparable to Jython. They're the implementation of the Python language. CPython is the de-facto standard and was written in C. Jython is written in Java and runs on the JVM. It also allows accessing the Java ecosystem to a great extent. There are also other implementation of the language, like PyPy or Pyston.

Cython is totally different. It allows us to write extensions for Python in C or Pyrex, a subset of the Python language. Cython speeds up the execution speed for the parts written with it.

Comment: OK, so should I remove the Jython part of my question if it's completely different? So basically I just write in Python, and then instead of writing certain tasks in C, I use "Cython" which is just as fast, except has the libraries of *both* languages and is basically Python except with some C syntax (Cython syntax), BUT, I cannot actually just write the program in Cython. Did I get it?

Comment: Cython is different. It works for CPython. Allows you to write some code in Python like syntax (with static typing and other syntactic differences). Cython compiles these codes to C and gains a performance boost. CPython and Jython are simply Python, one written in C, one in Java.

Comment: CPython == Jython (to some extent, not fully). Cython is an extension framework.

Comment: Use `Cython` to speed up selected functions in your larger `Python` program/package.  It gives the best speed improvement when it can rewrite the function as pure `c` code without calling `Python` functions or objects.  Usually that's iterative operations that expensive in regular Python.

Answer (score 0):

Jython is a implementation of Python language on the Java Virtual Machine, so Jython is Python but is not CPython. Cython is an extension to CPython and has not much in common with Python except some similarities in Syntax.